# (Module override/PHP) Checking if a content-item has an image otherwise display a placeholder

Tags: php, module, overrides, conditional-statements

I am customising a Joomla module (Override) and it does not seem to accommodate if an image is not selected (just shows a broken image symbol).

What I'd like to do is check if there is an image and if not, assign a placeholder image.

```
<div class="sp-portfolio-thumb">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $item->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" /></a>
    <div class="sp-portfolio-overlay">
        <div>
            <!--<a class="sp-portfolio-preview" rel="lightbox" title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->image_full; ?>"><?php echo JText::_('PREVIEW'); ?></a>-->
            <?php if($show_readmore){ ?>
                <a class="sp-portfolio-link" href="<?php echo $item->urls->urla; ?>"><?php echo JText::_('MORE_DETAILS'); ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried playing about with the part of the code relating to the image, but I'm clearly not very proficient in php.

```
<?php if ($item->image){ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $item->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" /></a>
<?php else ?>
    <img class="test" src="images/placeholder.jpg">
<?php } ?>
```

I'm getting:

> 0 - syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Can any one point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Please award green ticks on your historically resolved questions.  Those which are not resolved should be updated so that they progress toward a green ticked solution.

Comment: I recommend that you conduct your professional web development on a good IDE which will expose typos of this kind before you even execute it.  I am quite happy to endorse PHPStorm.  Before posting php errors (unrelated to Joomla!'s software), please research on Stackoverflow because this type of error has been posted hundreds of times there.

Comment: If I have not resolved those then I will not award them, I have multiple projects ongoing and come back to these issues and mark them resolved as and when I get back round to finishing them.

Comment: I'm not asking for green ticks where they are not earned.  I moreso wish to see progress on your questions that have stalled to abandonment despite answers being posted on them.

Answer (score 2):

Your are missing brackets around `else`:

```
<?php if ($item->image) { ?>
...
    <?php } else { ?>
...
<?php } ?>
```

You may also give alternative syntax a try, see if it's more readable to you:

```
<?php if ($item->image) : ?>
...
    <?php else : ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to initialize an `$image` variable earlier in your script like so:

```
$image = $item->image ? $item->image : 'images/placeholder.jpg';
```

The `$image` will get the value of the `$item->image` if it's set, or the placeholder file path you set.

Then you use the `$image` variable in place of the `$item->image` in your script. *You won't need the conditional test anymore, as the $image will always have a value.

So this part will look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" /></a>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want a hyperlink on the placeholder.  This doesn't perform as required.

Comment: Are you able to migrate this page to Stackoverflow where it belongs?

Comment: @mickmackusa - it's not clearly specified if having a hyperlink or not is a requirement. This may appear in the code provided by the OP, but it doesn't mean a lot. I answered to the part of his question that says: _"What I'd like to do is check if there is an image and if not, assign a placeholder image."_ Moreover, having links to the article either for the image, or the placeholder is a good thing for a consistent layout - but of course that may depend on what someone want to do... ;)

Comment: What needs to happen within JSE to add Stackoverflow as a place to migrate pages to? When I try to vote to Close and migrate, the only destination option is JSE Meta.

Comment: @mickmackusa - I had also this question in the early days of JSE. This simply isn't possible/available at the moment and we don't know much more about this feature. Let this question be here for now. If you like add a comment under the Q to mention that this type of questions are out of scope/ off-topic for JSE with a link to the related Help page (https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this in the end and requested the client manually add the placeholder image when creating the post.

Thank you all for your contributions.